# Do Galcon and Galcon Fusion track what boards or levels you've completed?

Tags: galcon, galcon-fusion

It seems like there's absolutely no reward for finishing a level.  You can start on the hardest level for each game type, and it doesn't even indicate which ones you've successfully won.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the Galcon games don't save completion statistics for levels; you're not missing anything. The game is more about online multiplayer than single player levels.